# О математической функции от нескольких аргументов

Tags: python, функции, математика

Положим, надо посчитать (b-a)/2 * (f(a) - f(b)), где f - любая функция.

```
def func(f1, f2, a, b):
    dif = f1 - f2
    approx = (b - a)/2 * dif
    return approx
from math import cos
a = 0
b= 1
f1 = cos(a)
f2 = cos(b)
func (f1, f2, 0,1)
```

это можно было сделать как-то рациональнее? спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def func(f,a,b):
    dif = f(a) - f(b)
    return (b - a)/2 * dif
```

Так достаточно рационально?

```
print(func(cos,0,1))
```

Comment: Вы знаете python?

Comment: @Danis чтобы заинлайнить ретурн в одну строку любом языке достаточно знаний любого другого языка 

Comment: @Danis На уровне чайника. А что? Написал что-то не то? Так вроде работает - https://ideone.com/cSFube

Comment: @Harry нет, все нормально. Просто не ожидал встретить вас

Comment: @Danis Ну так там стояла метка "математика", а ее я отслеживаю :)